# python-conda import not found even though the module is installed

Tags: python, windows, opencv, machine-learning, command-line

So, Hello there I just started learning Machine learning and opencv and was doing my project when i faced this error,

The Error is about **I can't use opencv in cmd prompt windows even though i can use it in VS Code using same kernel/environment** it gives error in cmd only

(Note - every package is installed with conda only all of them are not available in pip like opencv i will use below)

So here are the available packages:-

```
(Project) C:\Users\LE>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\LE\.conda\envs\Project:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asttokens                 2.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2023.5.7             h56e8100_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.7           py310h00ffb61_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
eigen                     3.4.0                h2d74725_0    conda-forge
executing                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    4.2.3                ha925a31_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h546665d_1    conda-forge
glib                      2.69.1               h5dc1a3c_2
gst-plugins-base          1.18.5               h9e645db_0
gstreamer                 1.18.5               hd78058f_0
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_he0bbb20_101    conda-forge
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
importlib-metadata        6.7.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        6.7.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h57928b3_46319    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.24.0             pyh6817e22_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.14.0             pyh08f2357_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   hcfcfb64_3    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.3.1           py310h5588dad_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  12.0.1          default_h81446c8_4    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.18                 hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_0
libhwloc                  2.9.1                h51c2c0f_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              17_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libprotobuf               3.20.3               h23ce68f_0
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.0                h8a3f274_0
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.3.1                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.1                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.10.3               h0ad7f3c_0
libxslt                   1.1.37               h0192164_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2022.1.0           h6a75c08_874    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.25.0          py310hd02465a_0    conda-forge
opencv                    4.6.0           py310h4ed8f06_3
openssl                   1.1.1u               hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       23.1.2          py310haa95532_0
platformdirs              3.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.38             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.38               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.5           py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
pthreads-win32            2.9.1                hfa6e2cd_3    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.15.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.10.9               h966fe2a_2
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
pywin32                   304             py310h00ffb61_2    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.0          py310hcd737a0_0    conda-forge
qt-main                   5.15.2               he8e5bd7_7
qt-webengine              5.15.9               hb9a9bb5_5
qtwebkit                  5.212                h2bbfb41_5
setuptools                67.8.0          py310haa95532_0
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.41.2               h2bbff1b_0
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.9.0             h91493d7_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h2bbff1b_0
tornado                   6.3.2           py310h8d17308_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.7.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.7.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h04d1e81_0
ucrt                      10.0.22621.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vc14_runtime              14.36.32532         hfdfe4a8_17    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.36.32532         h05e6639_17    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.38.4          py310haa95532_0
xz                        5.4.2                h8cc25b3_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                h0e60522_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.15.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h8cc25b3_0
zstd                      1.5.5                hd43e919_0
```

And This was the error Statement:-

```
(Project) C:\Users\LE>python solution.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LE\solution.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

(Project) C:\Users\LE>python
Python 3.10.9 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar  8 2023, 10:42:25) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

I Tried again using environemt.yml and making new kernel but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual environment named "Project" seems to have opencv, not opencv-python. To use cv2 library, install cv2 by typing `pip install opencv-python` and `import cv2` will work.
`conda list` will show opencv-python module.

Comment: It worked, but why is it like that can't I install opencv with conda?

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee this will work but I think you can try reinstalling with pip using `pip install opencv-python` and `import cv3` will work in the cmd (at least for me).